# Question closed because opinion based. How can I reword this question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, closed-questions

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19842/are-there-any-official-studies-to-support-cunninghams-law

I have since reworded my question to make it have a focus on asking for studies and/or statistics regarding the controversial Cunningham's Law. Is this enough for this question to be opened again? If not, what are some ways I can reword my question to get it reopened?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we can fix this question:

- The claim seems to be a "plausible joke", not a solid claim
- The claim is not extremely notable, even though it is likely notable
- The claim is extremely vague, as I commented under the question, making the question non meaningfully answerable
- Changing the claim would make the claim non-notable

Are there better notable versions of the claim? Examples of people taking it seriously?

Comment: I am not entirely sure which is why I posted it on Skeptics haha. If there is, I will update my question. Thank you for your honest opinion though.